# Ошибка expected unqualified-id before '{' token

Tags: c++

[image: Не могу понять, в чем проблема, я только начинаю, по этому очень туго]

Сидел уже 3 часа, много чего исправил, но с этой ошибкой ничего не получается решить

Comment: Возьми учебник, посмотри как пишутся функции.

Comment: с ошибкой разобрался, заработало, но не считает

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

double Ns(double N1,double N2,double N3,double N4,double N5,double N6){
   //тело функции
}

double dt(double T, double Tz) {
    //тело функции
}

double Nt(double v) {
    //тело функции
}

double Alfa(double L, double v, double dt) {
    //тело функции
}

double Z(double Ns, double Nr) {
    //тело функции
}

int main()
{
    //ваш исходный код.
    //
    //
    //в "..." передаете те параметры,которые нужны.
    Ns(...);
    dt(...);
    Nt(...);
    Alfa(...);
    Z(...);
}
```

Ну и да - нужно читать как пишутся и как работать с **функциями**. Впрочем и не только функции...